# BBC iPlayer ToolTip stays on screen

Tags: bug, mediaplayer

In MacOS Monterey, the tool tip stays popped-up on the screen and won't disappear. For example, here: [image]

Is there anything that can be done? I have recently formatted the hard drive and reinstalled Monterey (for another reason), but it persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same thing happens on my Windows PC on full screen view.

I found if I right click (some video info appears) and then left click this disables showing the Tooltip. Though you have to do this each time, its not an ideal solution but at least it works!

Comment: Yes this works, thank you. On mac I two-finger click, a small video info square appears, then I single click somewhere other than the menu, and wait. Then the mouse and player will disappear, leaving the full screen with no tool tip.

Comment: You're welcome of course. They changed BBCi Player recently so I believe this issue doesn't occur anymore. Maybe other people complained about this too!